# Table partitioning on external directory hitting "can't create table" error

Tags: mariadb, partitioning

I am trying to partition my tables by RANGE with the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE  main_table
    PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(date_val))(
     PARTITION old_db VALUES Less Than (TO_DAYS('2021-01-01'))
       DATA DIRECTORY = "/target/directory/",
     PARTITION new_db VALUES Less Than MAXVALUE
    );
```

I am able to do so with the same command and data table on my laptop but I hit this error on the server:
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `test`.`main_table` (errno: 168 "Unknown (generic) error from engine")

I sudo chown the external directory to "mysql" and restarted the mysql service and I am still getting this error.

Anybody have any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks!

This is the docs I am following:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/partitions-files/

My server DB version is on:
10.3.31-MariaDB

Comment: Are there any interesting messages in the MariaDB error log? Is the partition engine enabled?

Comment: Hi Mustaccio, thanks for responding. I checked INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS and the partition engine is enabled and active.

Comment: Indeed, there is something interesting on the mariaDB error logs:
[ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
[ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.

this is weird, given that I have already sudo chown the target directory to mysql:
drwxr-xr-x.  2 mysql    mysql        6 Aug 12 xx:xx mysql_p

Comment: Thanks @mustaccio for pointing me in the right direction. I realised one of the security policy was blocking mysqld from creating the mysql directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realised one of my server's security policy was blocking mysqld from creating the mysql directories. Resolved

Update:
OS version: Linux RHEL 7.4. I realised it was SELinux which was blocking the mysqld after each system reboot. I followed this post to test it out and configure SELinux to 'whitelist' mysqld - https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/selinux-and-mysql-v2

Comment: Please add more clues -- which OS?  What command was used to 'fix' the problem?